# System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary and KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, dictionary

Our ASP.NET MVC 3 use a model that exposes a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary via a property called Fields, we're using string for our keys.

We've noticed a KeyNotFoundException being thrown - but for a string key that we know is there!

This loop, when we have 3 items in the dictionary:

```
var ee = Model.Fields.GetEnumerator();
while (ee.MoveNext())
{
    logger.ErrorFormat("STRANGE ERROR: '{0}'", ee.Current.Key); 
    logger.ErrorFormat("STRANGE ERROR: {0}", ee.Current.Key.GetHashCode());          
}
```

Produces:

```
STRANGE ERROR: 'title'
STRANGE ERROR: -1859741728
STRANGE ERROR: 'link'
STRANGE ERROR: 325350890
STRANGE ERROR: 'view'
STRANGE ERROR: 1582259101
```

Yet, the following is false:

```
Model.Fields.ContainsKey("title") // Is False (incorrectly)
```

I was wondering if the hashcode was different, so tried:

```
string t = "title";
logger.ErrorFormat("STRANGE ERROR: {0}", t.GetHashCode());
```

Which produces:

```
-1859741728
```

So given I know the Dictionary contains my item and the string key hashes to the same code, why cant I access the Dictionary item?

**UPDATE**

Heres the view code to give a bit of context. This code is rough(!) its the product of some very quick diagnosis!

```
@using System.Xml.Serialization;
@using System.Text;
@using log4net;

@model IComponent

@{           
    string title = String.Empty;

    var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ContentModel.Component));
    logger.Error("STRANGE ERROR: CHECK TITLE");

    // Key in dictionary?
    if (Model.Fields.ContainsKey("title"))
    {
        logger.Error("STRANGE ERROR: CHECK TITLE: YES!");
        title = Model.Fields["title"].Value;
    }
    else
    {
        // No, loop through what fields we have
        var ee = Model.Fields.GetEnumerator();
        while (ee.MoveNext())
        {
            logger.ErrorFormat("STRANGE ERROR: '{0}'", ee.Current.Key); // 'title' appears - but failed above WTF!!!!
            logger.ErrorFormat("STRANGE ERROR: {0}", ee.Current.Key.GetHashCode());            
        }

        string t = "title";
         logger.ErrorFormat("STRANGE ERROR: {0}", t.GetHashCode());
    }
}

<h3>@title</h3>
```

Comment: Without seeing your entire view, model, and controller code, this would be pretty hard to debug. When does the dictionary get populated? Are you sure nothing else modifies it?

Comment: Does the Fields class overload/override any of the base implementations of CompareTo(), Equals(), etc?

Comment: How's Model.Fields defined? I would like to know the System.Type of your Key in the dictionary. If it's not "string", then that's why it's not working.

Comment: FYI (unrelated), `for` loops automatically use the `GetEnumerator()` stuff under the hood, why not switch out the `while` for `for (var ee in Model.Fields)` and drop the `ee` variable?

Comment: Your error is somewhere else. Is it possible that you have multiple threads using that dictionary and one is updating while another is reading? Have you checked the key and the value you're using to do the lookup to make sure that they don't have any hidden characters, leading or trailing spaces, etc? It's *possible* that the error is with `Dictionary`, but highly unlikely.

Comment: Are you passing a custom equality comparer to the `Dictionary` constructor?

Comment: I appreciate my code is a little ragged - but its only there for debugging purposes within my view.

Comment: Seeing the controller et al wont really help - all this crap code is taken straight out of one view (its only there as we where quickly debugging stuff). That's why its weird - the Model.Fields.ContainKey is called first as part of an "if" statement - the false side of which we emit lots of logging only to see that out key is there! Ill update my post.

Comment: Try calling `Model.Fields.ContainsKey("title")` again after the enumeration. If it returns `true`, this could mean that the value of `Fields` property is evaluated in some lazy fashion during enumeration.